# Javascript - Posting a form with AJAX and getting return values

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, json

I have now got everything to post correctly but this script keeps loading it into a new page. Is it something to do with the way my php file returns it? "echo(json_encode($return_receipt));"

```
    <script>        
    // Get XML HTTP Type
    function get_XmlHttp() {
        var xmlHttp = null;
            if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }else if(window.ActiveXObject) {
                xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
        return xmlHttp;
    }

    function ajaxSuccess () {
        alert(this.responseText);
    }

    function ajaxrequest(oFormElement,tagID) {
        //Get The Correct XMLHTTP Object
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();             
        request.onload = ajaxSuccess;
        request.open(oFormElement.method, oFormElement.action, true);
        //request.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.send(new FormData(oFormElement));           
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: You mentioned two forms .. but in html there is only one form.. can u explain furthere.

Comment: I have not actually added the other one in yet but I am going to have two forms that encase a table. The end goal is when the form is submitted I will save the data and add an extra extra row to the table with the new information. Right now I am just trying to save and see how the data looks when it is returned to me. Hence setting the return data to the text box.

Answer (score 0):

you have two easy options..

1.you can use jquery ajax method... or
2. javascript form submission without loading the page by targetting the form to the hidden inline frame

Comment: Can you expound on the second option a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

here i'm using it for image upload image name without hitting submit button and save the data to the database table **without reloading the page**.. edit it according to your convenience.

```
function upload(img)//Javascript function
{
var types = /\.jpg|\.gif|\.jpeg/i;
var filename = img.value;
if (filename.search(types) == -1) {
alert("Select only images ( jpg or gif or jpeg format)");
img.form.reset();
return false;
}

img.form.action = 'upload-picture.php';
img.form.target = 'iframe';
img.form.submit();
return true;
}
```

// here is iframe on the same page

```
<iframe name="iframe" id="u_iframe" style="display:none;"></iframe>


<input type="file" name="picture" id="picture" onchange="return upload(this);" />
```

Comment: How are you handling the information that is returned or are you not returning anything?

Comment: in the upload-picture.php file you can write save data options and after saving the data you can return it to the specified place of your page,